# Windows Phone 7: System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal does not work with COM

Tags: .net, com, windows-phone-7

I have two questions.

1)Does Windows Phone 7 support COM? .NET Framework knows such attributes like ComVisible, but I am not sure after all.

2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal misses any COM functions. Particularly, if the first question is answered positive, I miss StringToBSTR and GetObjectForNativeVariant. I am sure both functions can be written by myself, though it will take a while. Does anyone know what I should do in this situation?

What a pity OpenNETCF Smart Device Framework is not understood by Phone 7 .NET Framework.

.NET Framework is from Windows Phone SDK beta.

Comment: Is definitely a pity inter alia

Answer (score 1):

No COM in WP7. It's managed api's all the way.